# Angular 7 - Custom library - cannot export simple class

Tags: angular

I created a **custom library** that I published to use in my application

```
import { AccordionComponent } from 'my-angular-lib';
import { AccordionItemComponent } from 'my-angular-lib';
```

these two components are indeed included and display correctly

**but**, when I add a **simple class** which is not a directive/component..

```
export class Tools {
...
}
```

it just does **not find it** from my library module, **as I compile my application**

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(10,10): error TS2305: Module '"...../node_modules/my-angular-lib/my-angular-lib"' has no exported member 'Tools'.
```

although I declared it in the **public-api.ts**, I still cannot use it

```
export * from './lib/helpers/tools.class';
```

I also tried to add it in the main library module but it complained it had no **@Directive/@Component** tag

this is how I use it in my application

```
import { Tools } from 'my-angular-lib';
```

all the other components can be used and are found in the name space of my library without any issue

I already read many threads but none give me an alternative answer to solve this

Appreciate any help on this

[edit:]

if I try to add it to the imports/exports, I get

```
 Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
```

Why can't I just export it ?

my-angular-lib.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AccordionComponent } from './widgets/accordion/accordion.component';
import { AccordionItemComponent } from './widgets/accordion/accordionItem.component';

import { PaginationComponent } from './widgets/pagination/pagination.component';
import { PaginationService } from './widgets/pagination/pagination.service';

import { PasswordComplexityComponent } from './widgets/passwordComplexity/passwordComplexity.component';

import { UpDownComponent } from './widgets/updown/updown.component';

import { Tools } from './helpers/tools.class';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      AccordionComponent,
      AccordionItemComponent,
      PaginationComponent,
      PasswordComplexityComponent,
      UpDownComponent,
      Tools
  ],
  imports: [
      CommonModule,
      FormsModule
      ],
  exports: [
      AccordionComponent,
      AccordionItemComponent,
      PaginationComponent,
      PasswordComplexityComponent,
      UpDownComponent,
      Tools
  ],
  providers:[PaginationService]
})
export class MyAngularLibModule { }
```

public-api.ts

```
export * from './lib/my-angular-lib.module';

export * from './lib/widgets/accordion/accordion.component';
export * from './lib/widgets/accordion/accordionItem.component';

export * from './lib/widgets/pagination/pagination.component';
export * from './lib/widgets/pagination/pagination.service';

export * from './lib/widgets/passwordComplexity/passwordComplexity.component';

export * from './lib/widgets/updown/updown.component';

export * from './lib/helpers/tools.class';
```

Comment: After adding `export * from './lib/helpers/tools.class';`, have you build it again?

Comment: Is it normal that you import from `my-angular-lib` instead of `e5-angular-lib` ??

Comment: corrected, (the code is proprietary)

Comment: yes I re-built it

Answer (score 1):

In my Case removing the declare key word solve the build problem,

```
export declare class myClass{
    ...
}
```

Turns to

```
export class myClass{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finaly made it work

not really sure what went wrong, I recompiled the library with a new package.json version , republished it

and suddently my class could be found

strange since I did that a countless time yesterday